# Outbound links and iFrame

Tags: php, iframe, hyperlink

I want to replicate how digg.com treats their outbound links. They generate a short link which loads the outbound link's web page in an iFrame with a bar on top of the frame. I think there's a page template with the bar and iframe for all outbound links point to there.

So how would I make all links point to that page without actually changing one by one individually? What about the random letters in the link? I want to explore more insights.

Comment: Please think carefully about this.  That specific digg "feature" is questionable for several reasons.  For one, you're taking control away from the user -- if the user wants to navigate away from the page, that's up to them -- don't try to interfere.  Secondly, the shortened URLs make it impossible for people to know what they're clicking on; additionally, you confuse automated user agents (spiders, etc.).  Lastly, the iframe will break some pages, usually because they contain javascript that expects that the page won't be wrapped in an iframe.  Just let your links be links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this plugin for wordpress which is basically the digg bag: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-bar/